# Find 1 letter and 2 numbers using RegEx

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have been writing a program recently and a part of it requires me to get information form inside a string. I need to find where there is 1 letter immediately followed by 2 numbers (e.g. S07) and I can't work out the RegEx for it.

```
def get_season(filenames):
    pattern = "^[a-zA-z]{1}[\d]{2}$"
    found = re.search(filenames[0], pattern)
    season_name = found.string
    season = season_name[1:3]
    print(season)
```

I know that this information is in the string but it keeps giving me "None" in response

(I'm not too sure if the code section has formatted correctly, in the preview it shows as on the same line, but the indentation in my program is correct)

Comment: `s/a-zA-z/a-zA-Z/`; change `[\d]` to `\d`.

Comment: @devnull: That range is too wide, not too narrow. The `[..]` class is just redundant, it won't match anything less for it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I meant _substitute_ `a-zA-z` with `a-zA-Z`.

Comment: @devnull: yes, I understood that just fine (I am a VI user, coded Perl in a past lifetime). I am saying that `A-z` still includes `A-Z`, as well as everything between `Z` and `a`, then through to `z`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You swapped the arguments to `re.search()`. The first argument is the pattern, not the string to match:

```
found = re.search(pattern, filenames[0])
```

Your pattern is also overly wide; `A-z` matches everything between `Z` (uppercase) and `a` (lowercase) too. The correct pattern is:

```
pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]\d{2}$"
```

where `{1}` is the default, so I omitted that.

If you are matching this against filenames, you **probably** do not want to use the start or end anchors, that would limit matches to **exact strings** only:

```
>>> re.search("^[a-zA-Z]\d{2}$", "S07").string
'S20'
>>> re.search("^[a-zA-Z]\d{2}$", "S07E01 - Meet the New Boss.avi") is None
True
>>> re.search("^[a-zA-Z]\d{2}$", "S07E01 - Meet the New Boss.avi") is None
True
>>> re.search("[a-zA-Z]\d{2}", "S07E01 - Meet the New Boss.avi").string
'S07E01 - Meet the New Boss.avi'
```

And you want to use `.group()` to get the matched portion, not `string` (which is the original input string):

```
>>> re.search("[a-zA-Z]\d{2}", "S07E01 - Meet the New Boss.avi").group()
'S07'
```

If you only wanted the *numbers*, you need to add a group, and pick that. You create a capturing group with parenthesis:

```
>>> re.search("[a-zA-Z](\d{2})", "S07E01 - Meet the New Boss.avi").group(1)
'07'
```

This selects the first group (`.group(1)`), which is the parenthesis around the 2 digits portion.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex will catch only the string which consits only of one letter and two digits, to check whole string for multiple occurences use these:

Try this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z]\d{2}
```

**INPUT**

asdasdasS01asfasfsa

**OUTPUT**

S01

If you want to find a word wich consists only of a letter followed by two digits use this regex:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]\d{2}\b
```

Only numebers capture regex:

```
[a-zA-Z](\d{2})
```

**INPUT**

asdasdasS01asfasfsa

**OUTPUT**

01

---

Also swap the arguments in **serach** method.

Comment: The string is "S07E01 - Meet the New Boss.avi" which is an episode title for a TV show, I am trying to single out the part between the S and E

Comment: @user2099020 so you want only the numbers? If yes I have added thrid regex to my answer.